# misunderstanding of filehandle (or array?) in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, filehandle

New to perl (and language in general), and have gone so far as `OPEN FH`.
A little confused about the following two scenarios (outputs are different, but I couldn't understand why the second one is "wrong").

script 1

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open FILE, "example.txt" or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    print $_;
    }
```

script2

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open FILE, "example.txt" or die $!;
my @array = <FILE>;
while (<FILE>) {
    print $_;
    }
```

The example.txt contains 3 lines of sentence. When I assign filehandle `FILE` to an array, suddenly, `$_` becomes empty ??

If I replace `<FILE>` in the `while` loop with array (`@array`), the loop cannot stop and `$_` becomes "uninitialized value".

This is likely a very basic misunderstanding of `filehandle` and array , but can someone please help explain them - in plain English - ? Or point to the references where I could find more info (have a few references handy and have consulted them, but obviously I still couldn't quite understand why script 2 (and 3) are not correct). Great many thanks.

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/reading-from-a-file-in-scalar-and-list-context

Comment: thanks a lot for showing perlmaven !!

Comment: Looks like  Сухой27 solved your issue, but I want to point out that in Perl, it's a common idiom to use the three-arg open: 

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die "Can't open file: $!";

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. i saw that idiom in oreilly's books, but somehow the  "beginner book" (non-oreilly, I assume) did not follow that idiom. the program still runs without the traditional idiom but now i wonder if reading the beginner book is the right choice ??

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, when you read from a filehandle in a list context, it automatically reads to the end of the file. `$_` is empty because the entire file has been read into `@array`, and the filehandle has been moved to `EOF`. Perl's different handling of the same instruction in scalar and list "context" is unusual, but the behavior of the filehandle itself is pretty standard across languages. In general, a filehandle or input stream will let you read a line at a time, a byte at a time, or the whole file at a time, and have a pointer that keeps track of the last place in the file you read. When you inadvertently moved that pointer all the way to the end of the file (`EOF`) by doing a read in a list context, your next call to read a line finds that there's no more file to read. This is a pretty good explanation of [scalar and list context](http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl); that might be the trickier part of what's going on here.